# Initializing a global variable with integer-casted global variable pointer in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, initialization, standards, specifications

I found an unexpected 'invalid' C code snippet, which I believed a valid one:

```
char str[] = "test string";
int pstr2 = (int)str;
```

The second line raises the following compile error:

```
main.c:2:12: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
int pstr = (int)str;
           ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

It seems like that a casted global variable is not a compile-time constant, although the normal one is. Which part of C specification makes the second line erroneous?

**P.S.** I just wrote the code to reproduce a LLVM backend error I encountered. Thanks for tips anyway :)

Comment: How do you know an address fits in an `int`?

Comment: I was just trying to 'fabricate' the code to reproduce a LLVM backend error. Of course I don't use that kind of code in practice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which part of C specification makes this erroneous?

Since `pstr` is global, it has static storage duration. Therefore, section 6.7.8.4 of the C99 standard applies:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

The address of `"test string"` cannot be resolved until link time, and casting an address to `int` requires performing a calculation on a link-time value. This makes `(int)str` invalid for this context.

Note that link-time constants *without* calculations are allowed, e.g.

```
char *pstr = str;
```

is perfectly valid, because there is no cast.

**Note:** Since `int` is not guaranteed to hold the pointer in its entirety, consider using `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` type instead.

Comment: Thanks for referring the standard. But if the address of "test string" is treated like non-constant due to the reason you mentioned, shouldn't "char *pstr = str" raise a compile error too?

Comment: So it seems like that link-time constants loses their constantness if they are combined to any expression, other than itself. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you're doing

```
int pstr = (int)str;
```

in *global* space. A *statement* is not allowed to exist in global scope. It needs to be in function scope.

A special case, initialization while definition is allowed, but the condition is the initializer needs to be a compile time constant.

Here, `str` is not a compile time constant value. Hence the error.

FWIW, the `"test string"` is an unnamed *string literal* which is allowed to be used as initializer. So, the first statement is allowed.

Also, using `int pstr2 = (int)str;` is dangerous because whether a pointer will fit into an `int` or not is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

If this snippet of code is at the global level, i.e. outside of a function, the second line is indeed invalid.  Global variables can only be initialized with a constant expression.

Anything else is a statement and must reside in a function.

Comment: What's not constant about `(int)str`? What executable code do you see in `(int)str`?

Comment: Edited to refer to it as a statement

Answer (score 0):

This is not constant because casting to `int` could require conversion, e.g. on a Linux x86_64 system, where `sizeof(int)` is 4 while `sizeof(void *)` is 8. Generally, casting a pointer to an integer type could always require conversion, even if you use `intptr_t` (which you should ...), because this could be actually larger than your pointer.

In contrast, the following code would work:

```
typedef struct { char foo[1]; } test_t;
char str[] = "test string";
test_t *pstr2 = (test_t *)str;
```

So the problem ist not the cast itself.